# Can I take the self employment healthcare deduction if I get my insurance through my employer?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, health-insurance

Historically when I had insurance through ACA, I deducted the premiums on the special self employment premiums deduction. Now, I get insurance through my employer but still pay a ton for it. Is that still deductible against my self employment income? If not, can I still deduct anything above 10% of AGI on my Schedule A?

Comment: I would assume it's called a "**self employment** healthcare deduction" for a reason.

Comment: @user20574 OP *is* self-employed. It is a good question.

Answer (score 24):

The amount the employee pays for health insurance premiums is not included in your W-2 Box 1 income. As a result, it is automatically deducted, and you do not pay tax on that portion of your income. You cannot deduct it again on line 29 or on Schedule A, because the income is already deducted/not included on line 7.

Answer (score 8):

No, sort of. The employee portion is pre-tax, so it's already as if you deducted it.